# Default Document doesn't work in IIS 6 with .NET 4

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, .net-4.0

I just upgraded the .NET Framework from 3.5 to 4.0 on Windows 2003 x64.  IIS is configured to run in 32 bit mode.

When I run `aspnet_regiis -lv` I get the Framework64 and Framework of 4.0.30319.0 and the Framework of 2.0.50727.0 listed.

I have a web application with a virtual directory of `sems` and the `Documents -> Enable Default Content Page` is set to `default.aspx` (which is a valid page).  If I specify the `default.aspx` page in the URL it works correctly.

How can I get the default document to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is normally correct.  Default docs 'just work'.

The one thing that can turn off default documents is adding a wildcard script mapping.  i.e. * for aspnet_isapi.dll.  If you do that then you need to write your own default document handler since a / path is handled by .NET instead of IIS 6's default document handler.  That's my top guess on what is happening.